# add data to list with button in datalist or repeater

Tags: asp.net, .net, arrays, list, datalist

i cant add data to list in datalist please help me
i want to transfer some product to compare in other page
when i add value in page load it work but in repeater or datalist not work

this is my class

```
public class CAR
{

    private int carid;
    private string title;

    public CAR(int carid, string title)
    {
        this.carid = carid;
        this.title = title;
    }

    public int CARID
    {
        get
        {
            return carid;
        }
    }

    public string TITLE
    {
        get
        {
            return title;
        }
    }
}
```

this is the html side

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" OnItemCommand="DataList1_ItemCommand" runat="server" DataKeyField="id" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
        <ItemTemplate>
            id:
            <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("id") %>' runat="server" ID="idLabel" /><br />

            title:
            <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("title") %>' runat="server" ID="titleLabel" /><br />
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" CommandName="compare" Text="Button" />
            <br />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:DataList>
    <asp:SqlDataSource runat="server" ID="SqlDataSource1" ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:takyabConnectionString %>' SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [tbl_ad]"></asp:SqlDataSource>

    <asp:Button ID="Button2" OnClick="Button2_Click" runat="server" Text="Button" />
```

and it is codebehind

```
ArrayList value = new ArrayList();
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


    }


    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session.Add("v", value);
        Response.Redirect("webform2.aspx");
    }

    protected void DataList1_ItemCommand(object source, DataListCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "compare")
        {
            value.Add(new CAR(1,"ok"));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is that, on the first button click, you are adding the value to the ArrayList, of which the state is not saved during  the post back. Which means, on the Button2_Click event the array list will always be empty.

Change your value property something like this. Or Save the Arraylist value to the session in the DataList1_ItemCommand event itself

```
ArrayList value
{
get
{
   ArrayList values = null;
   if(ViewState["selectedValues"] != null)
     values = (ArrayList)ViewState["selectedValues"];
   else
   {
     values = new ArrayList();
     ViewState["selectedValues"] = values;  
   } 

  return values; 
}
}
```